# list of lists that splits on change between positive and negative values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Every time the item in a list changes from a positive to negative value, start a new sub-list. For the data:

```
khanh = [-2.22,1.4,2,3,4,5,6,0,-2,-3,-4,-5,7,8,9]
```

I'm trying to output:

```
[[-2.22],[1.4,2,3,4,5,6,0],[-2,-3,-4,-5],[7,8,9]]
```

My code so far:

```
adam = [[prev, next] for prev, next in zip(khanh, khanh[1:]+[None])]

amber = [[currentIdx,
          khanh[idx + 1] if idx < len(khanh) - 1 else None] for idx, currentIdx in enumerate(khanh)]

robby = [x for x in khanh if x > 0 ]

print(amber)
print()
print(adam)
```

Comment: Based on the post you've made, I would recommend spending some time reading documentation in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) so that you have the best chance at getting your question answered. Format your code, list what you have tried and where you think you've gone wrong, list what the expected output is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [-2.22,1.4,2,3,4,5,6,0,-2,-3,-4,-5,7,8,9]
>>> correct = [[-2.22],[1.4,2,3,4,5,6,0],[-2,-3,-4,-5],[7,8,9]]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> result = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda a: a < 0)]
>>> correct == result
True
```

Comment: omg, you are the man, i will go learn the itertools right now to understand it better, but you are a life saver, i was at it for 1 week trying to figure out how to do what you just showed me